# jquery paginate without update function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im writting a newsfeed, and I wonder how i would paginate on a page that does not refresh. When i click on a button i perform a json request to get new data, but i do not refresh the page.

Here is what i have:

HTML

```
<!-- Forum -->
<div id="forum"><center>Loading forum...</center></div>
<!-- Forum pagination -->
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous" id="forum-prev">
    <a href="#forum-top">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="next" id="forum-next">
    <a href="#forum-top">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function updateButtons()
{
// Button prev forum
$("#forum-prev").click(function() {
  var page = parseInt($.cookie("page"));
  page -= 1;
  $.cookie("page", page);
  loadforum();
  updateButtons();
});

// Button next forum
$("#forum-next").click(function() {
  var page = parseInt($.cookie("page"));
  page += 1;
  $.cookie("page", page);
  loadforum();
  updateButtons();
});
// Disable buttons
if($.cookie("page") >= 0)
{
  $("#forum-prev").removeClass("active");
  $("#forum-prev").addClass("disabled");
  $("#forum-prev").unbind("click");
}
else
{
  $("#forum-prev").removeClass("disabled");
  $("#forum-prev").addClass("active");
  $("#forum-prev").bind("click");
}
if($.cookie("page") <= parseInt($.cookie("forum-count"))-1)
{
  $("#forum-next").removeClass("active");
  $("#forum-next").addClass("disabled");
  $("#forum-next").unbind("click");
}
else
{
  $("#forum-next").removeClass("disabled");
  $("#forum-next").addClass("active");
  $("#forum-next").bind("click");
}
}
```

What would be the best way to paginate if i do not refresh the page, and the prev button should be disabled when on `page 0(default)` and enabled when `page > 0` and next should be disabled when `page < maxPage`. I tried using `$.on()` `$.off()` but i have the same issue since the JS doesnt reload I cannot enable buttons or disable.

Comment: What if your user wants to open 2 different pages in 2 different browser tabs?

Comment: well its more of a newsfeed, but i suppose this will not be an option as the way i created it.

Comment: So - no search engine crawlers, no multiple tabs. Is your real aim to get the worst UX? ;-)

Comment: :D I realize this isnt the idea setup, its a bit late to change my setup. I will in the future look into how to better it. The project aim is to learn MongoDB. I will revisit the setup at another time.